# Recursively rename directories and files based on a regular expression

Tags: regex, linux, bash, pcre

I am trying to strip all "?" in file names in a given directory who was got more subdirectories and they have subdirectories within it. I've tried using a simple perl regex script with system calls but it fails to recurse over each subdirectory, and going manually would be too much wasted time. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Where is this perl code oO ? Show us...

Comment: It just parses the output of "ls -R | grep '?'", regexes the file names and issues a system call to rename them. It does not work very ok, I found that using both "find" and "rename" you could make this work very easily, but I couldn't understand both's mind-numbing documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **find** command to search the filenames with "?" and then use its *exec* argument to run a script which removes the "?" characters from the filename. Consider this script, which you could save to `/usr/local/bin/rename.sh`, for example (remember to give it +x permission):

```
#!/bin/sh
mv "$1" "$(echo $1| tr -d '?')"
```

Then this will do the job:

```
find -name "*\?*" -exec rename.sh {} \;
```

Comment: I'd rather use someone else's code (like rename or others), thanks anyway.

Comment: Sure! I just put your script in case you wanted to use it anyway but with find resolving the dir recursion part. I'll try using rename or something instead...

Comment: Is the "?" located anywhere in the name or always at the end or something?

Comment: I have to go now... later I post you a short one you could use in place of "rename.pl"

Comment: This last edit should do it. It will even strip "?" from dir names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
find -name '*\?*' -exec prename 's/\?//g' {} +
```

See https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.06/rename.PL (this is the default `rename` command on Ubuntu distros)

Comment: What is your error ? Have you seen my link ? If it's a "command not found", then you should consider installing `prename`

Comment: No error (ie the program returned 0). It just does not "act" (do anything at all).

Answer (score 0):

Find all the names with '?' and delete all of them. Probably -exec option could be used as well but would require additional script

```
for f in $(find $dir -name "*?*" -a -type f) ; do
    mv $f ${f/?/}
done
```